# Symfony + AngularJS 401 unauthorized error after Get method

Tags: angularjs, symfony, get, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I have some concerns(marigolds) with my method GET when I send my request. I have received an error 401 and I am disconnected from the application, knowing that the token which I obtain in the console is very valid when I test on postman. I does not really understand(include) why that does not work I have to add some things or I have pain make something.

```
var list = function(){
    var mytoken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    return $http({
            method  : 'GET',
            url     : apiEndpoint.url + '/list',
            withCredentials : true,
            headers : {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + mytoken}
        }).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data);
    });
};
```

If somebody could me helped please, thank you :)

Comment: I haven't had to wrap my token in curly brackets before. What is the reason?

Comment: It was just a test to have the same result as on Postman .. but that I remove the brackets or not it is always the same result, 401 ..

Comment: When you have broken code, don't break it more and then post **double broken code**. Please edit your answer to show your best attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that she uses of the angularJS in her project, while RequestOptions is a class which we find that in Angular 2. That's why the import does not work

It must be added in the `conf` of `apache`:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization. + HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = $ 0
```

It should work for your case :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check it like below:

```
        let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + YourToken);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.get('YourUrl', options)
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I get the following error: RequestOptions is not defined
Unfortunately I am a noob yet on angularjs of the blow I do not know where to add "import"

Comment: do You use TypeScript?

Comment: Hum nop, I have not used TypeScript so far

Comment: I put import {RequestOptions} from '@ angular / http'; In the app.component.ts file but still the same error RequestOptions is not defined